# Attempt to sum output returns TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am attempting to sum the total file sizes of specific file types. I am able to identify all the targeted files and get the sizes in bytes but I am running into an issue when trying to sum the output. I feel like I need to convert my output to a different type to execute `print(sum(file_size))`

Here is the code I have currently and the outputs.

```
from pathlib import Path

# get file path
for path in Path('C:\Users\file\path\here').rglob('*.kml'):

# get size of file
    Path(path).stat()
    file_size =Path(path).stat().st_size
    print(file_size)
```

Output:

```
72830
109576
179554
165898
63151
193100

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My end goal is to have all of these outputs summed. Any help?

Comment: initialize a running total to 0 before the for loop and add file size at each iteration. Then print the running total after the loop

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted to do already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to keep track of the sum, and add the file size to it in each iteration:

```py
from pathlib import Path

total_file_size = 0
# get file path
for path in Path('C:\Users\file\path\here').rglob('*.kml'):

# get size of file
    Path(path).stat()
    file_size =Path(path).stat().st_size
    print(file_size)
    total_file_size += file_size
print(total_file_size)
```

Comment: You should avoid using the variable name sum as it will mask the builtin python sum function

Comment: It looks like the last size printed is the last file in the folders rather than a sum of all files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and sum the results:

```
from pathlib import Path
print(sum(path.stat().st_size for path in Path('C:\Users\file\path\here').rglob('*.kml')))
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response Mark. This did exactly what I needed it to do. Do you have any resources or documentation on how a list generator works? Thanks again!

Comment: @sungliengk I linked to the PEP that introduced them above.  They are also demonstrated in the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)